# Append a row of data to jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I am doing small project in java swing using JTable. When user select value from JComboBox I would like to add it to JTable. I have tried some code but it doesn't work. Please give some suggestions.

Comment: please always add your code, to clarify your question and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

The key is in your use of a model, and the easiest solution is to have your JTable use a DefaultTableModel for its model and call its `addRow(...)` method to add a "row" of data to the JTable. There are many examples of just this sort of thing on this and other sites if you look.

If you need more specific help, then yes, post your code including the code that doesn't work, and ask specific questions. Best to post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

Declare a model to your table and just add rows to the table using the model

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(dtm);

// Add Columns
dtm.addColumn("Col1");
dtm.addColumn("Col2");

// Add row data
dtm.addRow(...);
dtm.addRow(...);
```

Read about [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) for knowing different methods it has.